# How to ORDER BY within LEFT JOIN in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL 5.7.32 I have two tables. One holding products, the other holding characteristics with a date associated. There can be n amounts of characteristics but only the one with the newest date ist the one I am interested in.

products:

```
ID | NAME
1  | skoda
2  | bmw
```

content:

```
PROD_ID | TYPE  | CONTENT | DATE
1       | color | red     | 2020-12-25
1       | color | green   | 2020-12-24
1       | size  | big     | 2020-12-24
2       | color | yellow  | 2020-12-24
2       | size  | small   | 2020-12-24
2       | size  | big     | 2020-12-20
2       | color | purple  | 2020-12-20
1       | color | black   | 2020-12-01
```

As you can see the design serves as kind of a change log which is why they are not stored in a "regular" way.

Now the tricky part is to get the latest content of any type for each product.

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
NAME | COLOR | SIZE
skoda| red   | big
audi | yellow| small
```

I could do simple left joins:

```
SELECT
    p.name,
    c.content  AS color,
    c2.content AS size
LEFT JOIN content c  ON c.prod_id  = p.id WHERE c.type = 'color'
LEFT JOIN content c2 ON c2.prod_id = p.id WHERE c2.type = 'size'
GROUP BY p.id
```

There are 2 problems:

1. I want the latest color and size by date. How to order by date in left join?
2. There are many content types. How to do that with one LEFT JOIN and pick the type within SELECT?

Is there a way in MySQL 5.7 to do this?

Comment: Please post the expected output as well.

Comment: Yes, I just updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that with two subqueries:

```
select p.name
    (
        select c.content 
        from content c 
        where c.prod_id = p.id and c.type = 'color'
        order by c.date desc limit 1
    ) as color,
    (
        select c.content 
        from content c 
        where c.prod_id = p.id and c.type = 'size'
        order by c.date desc limit 1
    ) as size
from product p
```

This query would take advantage of an index on `content(prod_id, size, date desc, content)`.

Alternatively, you can `left join` once and do conditional aggregation:

```
select p.name,
    max(case when c.type = 'color' then c.content end) as color,
    max(case when c.type = 'type' then c.content end) as type
from product p
left join content c 
    on  c.prod_id = p.id
    and c.date = (
        select max(c1.date)
        from content c1
        where c1.prod_id = c.prod_id and c1.type = c.type
    )
group by p.id
```

Comment: I was hoping for something smaller, like one join and then pick the color within select. The query s already very complex, this minimal example beeing a small part of it. After group by all values seem to be known, e.g. a count on the content column shows amount of different colors, so I hoped the latest one could simply be selected.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for illustrating the alternative. Never saw contitional aggregation before.

Comment: Please allow me one more question. The alternative takes much longer >2s instead of 100ms. Could this be solved by additional indexes?

Comment: @merlin: the same index that is showed in the answer for the subquery solution might help the conditional aggregation solution. But I think that the correlated subquery is more efficient for your use case.

Comment: Stupid me forgot an index on the date column. That funny enough shaved of only about 100ms on the first solution. I stick with it, returns all results in under 300ms, good enough.